# MissingPluginException on firebase_core

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Earlier the application was running fine, suddenly today it started showing this error on startup related to firebase initialization.

```
D/eglCodecCommon(12224): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
E/flutter (12224): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
E/flutter (12224): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:154
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224): #1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:342
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224): #2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224): #4      Firebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224): #5      main
package:resolve_app/main.dart:18
E/flutter (12224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12224):
```

**Steps that are already performed before asking this:**

- flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter run
- Changes in mainactivity file (given in some answers previously)
- Complete restart of app, change of device (tried on 2 physical device and 1 emulator)

firebase_core is on 1.7.0

*Added cloud functions recently to the project, will that be a cause for it if some configuration is missed ? (Regenerated google-services.json already)*

**EDIT:**
After getting no clue, I cloned my project again from github and tried building it, and it worked. Still don't know what would have caused this

Comment: update the version if didn't solved try importing firebase_core as module